# Fitting a power law: "NaN computed by model function"

Tags: matlab, model-fitting

I try to fit a power law function with matlab (y=ax^b)

[Here are my x and y matrices](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3vh095ga3u2oomo/AACv0CJH9b-n2_1Y3knUk3XGa?dl=0)

I simply compute the fitting with

> fit(x,y,'power1')

I get this error:

> Error using fit>iFit (line 415)
>   NaN computed by model function, fitting cannot continue.
>   Try using or tightening upper and lower bounds on coefficients.
>   Error in fit (line 109)
>   [fitobj, goodness, output, convmsg] = iFit( xdatain, ydatain, fittypeobj, ...

WHYYYY!? There is no 0 in my x and y matrices, nothing that would return a NaN value I think, and I can compute without any problem the inverse relationship fit(y,x,'power1').

Thanks for any help/suggestion!!

EDIT: (just as a precision) Excel does find a power law fit for (x,y)!

EDIT2 : code, once x and y are stored as variables.:

```
[p_powerlaw,results_powerlaw] = fit(x,y,'power1');
```

EDIT3: I have changed the link. Now there, in my dropbox, you will find the .mat of x and y...try to fit them with the power1... :P doesn't work! why? I don't get it...

And try to copy paste the values of the 2 matrices x and y into other matrices (not by assigning, really by copy-pasting the values)...no problem with the fitting..!

Comment: I think the problem is not that you have or no 0s, but if the fitting algorithm can or can not rech the solution. Unfortunatedly, not everything can be fitted :(. However, I am not sure if this is the case.

Comment: Thanks Anders. But just stupidly thinking, when I plot the data, there are no outliers, it's pretty smooth. AND EXCEL FINDS A FIT!!!

Comment: mmmm I executed it and i got the result... a =       13.42 b =      0.9464

Comment: in Matlab??? fit(x,y,'power1') with my x and y???

Comment: Yup. I didnt get any error. Just executed it and thats it.

Comment: UUH!ok I email the Matlab dudes then. I tried it on other versions of Matlab, to which I have access here...got the same error. thanks! I will get back to you when I get the "official" answer!

Comment: mm Make sure you are doing it rigth first.... post your whole code (it should be about 3-4 lines)

Comment: I have just posted the only code I have...

Comment: My guess is that maybe x and y are not stored properly. have you tried transposing them?

Comment: The fitting works only if the inputs are column vectors.

Comment: +both are stored as double. And I can fit with power2, with pretty much everything I have tried. only power1 is problematic..

Comment: hi again...check my EDIT3....

Comment: Hi, You are rigth. Can you post also the previous TXT? if its the same data it shoudl work...

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent to `fit` in Octave, however, I can do some nonlinear curve fitting (the MATLAB equivalent would be either [`lsqcurvefit`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/optim/ug/lsqcurvefit.html) or [`lsqnonlin`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html) the optimization toolbox):

```
% Define function handle for optimisation (equivalent to power1 fit in MATLAB)
f = @(p, x) p(1) * x.^p(2);

% Initial guess for power law coefficients
init = [1 1]';

% Run optimisation - data is contained in X matrix
[p,y_power,cvg,op] = nonlin_curvefit(f,init,X(:,1),X(:,2));

% Sort out the fitted data to be monotonically increasing
Y = zeros(size(X));
[Y(:,1),idx] = sort(X(:,1),1);
Y(:,2) = y_power(idx);

% Plot the data
plot(X(:,1),X(:,2),'x',Y(:,1),Y(:,2))

% Display the power law coefficients
clc
disp('y = a * x^b');
disp(['a = ' num2str(p(1))])
disp(['b = ' num2str(p(2))])
```

This gives me the following coefficients (the same as @Ander Biguri) and graph:

```
y = a * x^b
a = 13.416
b = 0.94642
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! thanks for you answer. But I doubt it's that, because if I try to fit a power function the other way around ("fit(y,x,'power1')"), there's no problem. Anyway, you don't have to sort your data for fitting. .. :(

Comment: OK, I'll remove my answer then.

Comment: Don't! answers are always important... :)

Comment: Edited my answer to show it is possible to get a power law fit to the data.

Comment: hey! thanks again. but are you sure you are fitting a power law here? power law function (with an exponential expression) is more like y = a * exp(b * ln(x)) rather than y = a * exp (b*x)

Comment: uh wait wait...a * x^b = a * exp(b * ln (x)) (if x not equal to 0), no doubt about that. In your script, if I understood it correctly, you have asked the fitting with the function f = @(p, x) p(1) * exp (p(2) * x), which looks to me like a*exp(bx), which is not a * x^b...or am I off the thing? EDIT : ok :)

Comment: urf ok. Well I guess it's a bugg in my matlab version or something like that... will try to sort this out and come back here...

Comment: Maybe try giving an initial guess to point the algorithm in the right directions using `fitoptions`. Also try to experiment in the curve fitting `cftool` with the different fit options. See http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/curvefit/parametric-fitting.html#bszh0sy-13